# How to access a child element using jquery?

Tags: html, jquery

Suppose I have a block of code that looks like this.

```
    <div class="lv1">

         <div class="lv2">

             <div class="img">
             </div>
             
             <div id="text-on-image">  // <-- I want to grab  this div element.      
             </div>     

         </div>

         <div class="lv2">
         </div>
    </div>
```

Now I have $(this).eq(0) which refers to the root div element.

```
    <div class="lv1">  //<-- $(this).eq(0) is here.

         <div class="lv2">

             <div class="img">
             </div>
             
             <div id="text-on-image">       
             </div>     

         </div>

         <div class="lv2">
         </div>
    </div>
```

$(this).eq(0).children().eq(0) now refers to first div of lv2 class div.

```
    <div class="lv1">  

         <div class="lv2"> // <-- $(this).eq(0).children().eq(0) is here

             <div class="img">
             </div>
             
             <div id="text-on-image">       
             </div>     

         </div>

         <div class="lv2">
         </div>
    </div>
```

$(this).eq(0).children().eq(0).children().eq(1) now refers to the correct div I want.

```
    <div class="lv1">  

         <div class="lv2">

             <div class="img">
             </div>
             
             <div id="text-on-image"> // <-- $(this).eq(0).children().eq(0).children().eq(1) is here      
             </div>     

         </div>

         <div class="lv2">
         </div>
    </div>
```

Notice how the selecting child node became very messy for my code.

"$(this).eq(0).children().eq(0).children().eq(1)"

Is there a better way to go about doing the same work?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**If you used id, you can select it right away.**

```
$("#text-on-image")
```

**id must be unique, so if you use class, you can use ".find()"**

```
$(".lv1").find(".text-on-image")
```

**If no id or class is specified, selectors can be used.**

```
$(".lv1 > .lv2 > div:nth-child(2)")
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

`$("#parent").find(".children")`  for all children (deep traverse)

or:

`$("#parent").children(".children")`  for immediate children

---

Since you use an ID, and an ID **must be unique** - simply use `$("#text-on-image")`
Otherwise, use the `.find()` Method.

Comment: That answers me question thank you. But what if I used a class, then how would I do it ?

Comment: @7906jun just use `$('.lv1 > .lv2 > .text-on-image')`